# Est-il pertinent/souhaitable de reformuler le titre d'une question ?

Tags: discussion, editing, question-quality

J'évoque notamment le cas de questions dont la formulation initiale se révèle maladroite après quelques réponses, et qu'une révision permettrait de corriger.

Le cas concret qui a suscité ma question est [celui-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/quadricephale-comment-appelle-t-on-ce-barbarisme-specifique). J'ai posé ma question, et les réponses m'ont aidé à trouver une meilleure formulation, que j'ai ajoutée en fin de question.

Cependant, dois-je éditer mon titre pour le remplacer par la seconde formulation ? Si oui, les réponses ne vont-elles pas se retrouver en quelque sorte « en décalage » avec cette nouvelle question ?

---

**English reader short version :** 
Is redacting a question's title a good practice, when some answers have already been posted? Is it worth for question quality? Won't early answers become somewhat off-scope after the question has been reshaped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans ce cas il s'agit d'une généralisation de la question, je ne vois pas en quoi ça peut gêner de la reformuler ainsi.

Je pense que c'est une bonne initiative de reformuler la question en fonction des réponses, qui permettent souvent de mieux comprendre ce qu'on cherchait. On ne le fait pas souvent par peur de casser l'enchaînement des réponses, mais il est toujours possible d'ajouter un commentaire sous la réponse en expliquant la reformulation dans les cas les plus problématiques. Ça ne doit pas être un changement radical, l'auteur doit pouvoir rapidement adapter sa réponse s'il juge que c'est nécessaire.

Dans certains cas, il faut quand même faire attention à une chose supplémentaire : quelqu'un qui se poserait la question exactement telle qu'elle était anciennement formulée doit être capable de trouver la nouvelle formulation lorsqu'il fait une recherche. Il faut être sûr que les mots clés de l'ancien titre sont préservés ou qu'ils se trouvent quelque part dans le corps de la question. Idem pour les exemples canoniques.

Answer (score 6):

Le titre d'une question est souvent la seule chose qu'un futur visiteur va lire avant de décider s'il suit un lien vers la page. Donc il vaut mieux qu'il soit aussi clair que possible. À ce titre, je trouve « Y a-t-il un nom pour désigner les mots composés de racines linguistiques hétérogènes ? » bien meilleur que « Quadricéphale : comment appelle-t-on ce barbarisme spécifique ? ». Le premier annonce clairement ce qui est recherché, le deuxième cite seulement un exemple (et pas des plus courants).

Il est toujours bienvenu d'éditer une question pour la rendre plus claire ou plus facile à trouver. Il faut bien sûr ne pas en changer significativement le sens, et en particulier veiller à ce que les réponses restent valides.

Comment: Sans plus un, sans moins un. Juste une lecture : j'ai plus tendance à ouvrir (ou envie d'ouvrir) le lien "Quadricéphale ..." qui m'ouvre des perspectives de découverte de la langue, plutôt que la rébarbative question universitaire savamment dosé de termes académiques, normalisés, qualifiés ISO-xxx-yy, mais sans saveur - Peut-être ajouter "Quadricéphale (deux racines linguistiques) ...".

Comment: @cl-r La plupart des visiteurs tombent sur une question parce qu'ils ont fait une recherche. La probabilité pour que quelqu'un ait cherché *quadricéphale* (et non *télévision* ou *automobile*) est faible.

Comment: @Gilles Juste pour nuancer ton propos : c'est vrai pour les visiteurs extérieurs au site, mais pas pour les membres plus ou moins réguliers, qui viennent jeter un oeil aux questions actives. Et ce sont eux, la plupart du temps, qui répondent, raison pour laquelle il n'est pas absurde de vouloir leur "donner envie" de lire la question, ce à quoi cl-r faisait référence.